# to get random id using php and mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a 2 tables which contain 
id,subject,exam,qution,qution_id, in table 1
in table 2 
id,question_id,answer,correct,
 here i have a problem to get a random questions from data base 
i am using

```
$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question'  LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($singleSQL)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $thisQuestion = $row['question'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $subject =$row['subject'];
        $exam =$row['exam'];
        $explan =$row['explan'];
        $question_id = $row['question_id'];
        $s ='<strong>'.$subject.'</strong>';
        $e ='<small>'.$exam.'</small>';
        $q = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';
        $ex ='<p class="exp">'.$explan.'</p>';
        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand()");
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
            $answer = $row2['answer'];
            $correct = $row2['correct'];
            $answers .= '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"> <tr>
            <td><label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'">'.$answer.'</label></td>
            </tr></table>
            <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br />
            ';

        }
        $output = ''.$s.','.$e.''.$q.','.$answers.''.$ex.' <span id="btnSpan"><button onclick="post_answer()" id="show">Submit</button></span>';
        echo $output;
       }
    }
```

when i click submit answer i should get a next question randomly 
like

```
 index.php?question=
```

what should i use here 
when ever a page loads it should get a random question from database 
plz help iam in need of this 
thanx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Comment: mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: You have to return 4th row Luke. http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Can't you just add ORDER BY RAND() to your first query, just like you are doing in the second query?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use an array to store the question id's, and use php's rand function to generate a random number (which will be between 0 and the size of the list), which would be the index of the list of question id's.

```
int rand ( int $min , int $max )
```

Comment: sir i have created an array with an session plz check the code tel me where i have to use rand eliment                                $sql =     mysql_query("SELECT id FROM questions");
 $numQuestions = mysql_num_rows($sql);
 if(!isset($_SESSION['answer_array']) || $_SESSION['answer_array'] < 1){
  $currQuestion = "1";
 }else{
  $arrCount = count($_SESSION['answer_array']);

Answer (score 0):

```
$randomparameter = mysql_query("SELECT MIN(id) as min_id,MAX(id) as max_id FROM questions ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($randomparameter );
$random_questin_id=rand($row['min_id'],$row['min_id']);
```